# Inserting multiple elements at same position in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, adjacency-list

This is code for representing adjacency list using vector in C++(from geeksforgeeks).

```
// A utility function to add an edge in an 
// undirected graph. 
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v) 
{ 
    adj[u].push_back(v); 
    adj[v].push_back(u); 
} 

// A utility function to print the adjacency list 
// representation of graph 
void printGraph(vector<int> adj[], int V) 
{ 
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v) 
    { 
        cout << "\n Adjacency list of vertex "
             << v << "\n head "; 
        for (auto x : adj[v]) 
           cout << "-> " << x; 
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    int V = 5; 
    vector<int> adj[V]; 
    addEdge(adj, 0, 1); 
    addEdge(adj, 0, 4); 
    addEdge(adj, 1, 2); 
    addEdge(adj, 1, 3); 
    addEdge(adj, 1, 4); 
    addEdge(adj, 2, 3); 
    addEdge(adj, 3, 4); 
    printGraph(adj, V); 
    return 0; 
}
```

addEdge(adj,0,1) and addEdge(adj,0,4) both push_back values 1 and 4 at position 0. So my question is can we insert two or more values at same position in vector? Does it create some sort of linked list at a particular position of vector when more than one values are inserted into that position? If not, can please someone explain the working of above code.

Comment: `vector<int> adj[]` is a pointer to an array of vectors.

Comment: You should read up on what push_back actually does: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `vector` to insert more than one values at a position.

Declaration `vector< vector<int> > adj[V];`

Now to insert a value at position 0 you can use like this

```
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v, int val) 
{ 
    adj[u][v].push_back(val); 
    adj[v][u].push_back(val); 
}
```

To add element

```
addEdge(adj, 0, 0, 1); // insert 1 at position (0,0)
```

Please keep in mind that before adding element you need to initialize `vector` at every `index`.

But you can't insert two or more values at same position in vector.

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is can we insert two or more values at same position in vector

No, we can't. A vector contains exactly one element in each index. No more; no less. Just like an array.

> Does it create some sort of linked list

No. Vector is implemented using a dynamic array; not a linked list.

> can please someone explain the working of above code.

`vector<int> adj[V]` is an array of vectors. Each vector represents the adjacency list of the vertex identified by the index where the vector is stored, and each of those vectors can contain multiple elements.